# Advanced error handling in Spring Boot (Filter errors, Thymeleaf errors, startup errors)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot web project that needs a lot of custom error handling. In detail I need error handling for the following components:

- Controllers (divided between `RestController` and normal `Controller`; already done this)
- Thymeleaf errors
- Filter errors
- Configuration & startup errors
- fallback handling when default error page encounters an error somewhere in the filter chain

So far I figured out that I can handle thymeleaf and filter errors with a high-precedence exception handling filter. However, I am really struggling in actually handling the error. My goal is to show a default error page. However, if that error page encounters an error (for example another thymeleaf or filter error), I want to show a bare-bone HTML error page instead.

Also, I have not found out how to handle configuration & startup errors so far.

Are these things possible with Spring Boot?

Comment: [This post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) may help.